# How to filter a boolean column on ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

This question is related to the [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin) gem. I'm trying to filter a column that has a boolean type but with no success: `filter :column_name` and `filter :column_name, :as => :boolean` don't work.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`filter :column_name, :as => :select` will create a drop down with values "Any", "True", "False"

Comment: You need to add the __collection__ option or one of the (True/False) values could not be present, if all values in the recordset are the same. This way     `  :as => :select, collection: [['True', true], ['False', false]]  `

Answer (score 12):

As of ActiveAdmin 0.6.2, using `filter :column_name, as: :select` now has the horrible side effect of doing a complete table scan.  Plus, its options are now "Any", "true", "false".

For example, if I have a `District` model with the boolean column `enabled` then `filter :enabled, as: :select` generates the query `SELECT DISTINCT "districts"."enabled" FROM "districts" ORDER BY enabled asc` to obtain the 3 values.  My districts table is quite large, so this is clearly not what I want.

OTOH, while I can now use `filter :column_name, as: :boolean`, it uses a checkbox that defaults to not being checked, which is again not what I want.

To restore the pre-0.6.2 behavior, I had to do this: `filter :enabled, as: :select, collection: [["Yes", true], ["No", false]]`.  ActiveAdmin drops in the "Any" value for me.

Comment: another side efect of using as: :select and the full scan. If there are no fields with, for example 'false' values, then the select does not contains the 'false' option!

Answer (score 2):

Similarly, if you need to use checkboxes, do:

```
filter :column_name, as: :check_boxes
```

This will create checkboxes with the names `Yes` and `No`, whose values are `true` and `false` respectively.

If you want to customise the names, and maybe even the label? Then do:

```
filter :column_name, label: "Custom Column Name", as: :check_boxes, collection: [["Paid", true], ["Not paid", false]]
```

Though you can use checkboxes(it works!), I recommend using `as::select` as it 'remembers' the chosen value (on the UI) after page refresh. Checkboxes don't yet have this feature as of activeadmin version 1.2.1