# ActiveAdmin filter boolean as single checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

How can i filter a boolean value using a single checkbox?

For example the following gives me two checkboxes with `yes` and `no` values:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do    
  filter :is_retired, :as => :check_boxes
end
```

HBTM association is filtered as follows:

```
filter :roles_id, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => proc { Role.all }
```

But i have a boolean field in my `User` model and need a single checkbox with `Is retired` label. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: IMO it doesn't really make sense to do this. If the checkbox is checked, it suggests you want to search where `is_retired` is `TRUE`; while unchecked you want to search where `is_retired` is `FALSE`. You're never able to search for either `TRUE` **or** `FALSE` with a single checkbox. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608788/how-to-filter-a-boolean-column-on-activeadmin

Answer (score 2):

```
filter :is_retired,
  as: :check_boxes,
  collection: [['Yes', true]],
  label: 'Retired?'
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608788) use 
`filter :enabled, as: :select, collection: [["Yes", true], ["No", false]]`